# Drupal and moodle

Tags: 7

Currently old website is using moodle platform. 
If user want to login, it require three things. 
1) System - Which system are they going to use? System A or System B
2) Login ID
3) Password

Now I intend to change to Drupal 7 and add one new System call (System C). However, if user login to old system (System A or System B), it will still link to old moodle website.

I decide to move moodle file from root directory to sub domain and add drupal 7 to root directory. If user choose new course, it will remain in drupal. (www.the-example.com)(main domain) If user choose old courses, it will go old moodle website. (www.the-example.com/old_system)(sub-domain)

I wonder can the Drupal detect System A or System B it can redirect to www.the-example.com/old_system. Can I do that? Seek for your advice.

Comment: It depends all on the fact Moodle can integrate with Drupal login system. This is more a question for Moodle than Drupal.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Basically I can create a subdomain and move moodle into it. Then I may use main for my drupal, this should be no issue.

My concern is when user select old systems, it will redirect page to moodle. For this I would like to have some advice from here. Most likely I need to modify url path to link to moodle, but how?

Comment: If you are going to copy all the installation files in the same directory, then it will not work. Also there are two things that are not clear: What do you mean by system (e.g. _System A_ and _System C_)? Is the login method you are describing (the one that allows to choose between _System A_ and _System b_) part of Moodle?

Comment: Anyway, this requires knowledge of Moodle. If you are able to rewrite the question in a way that doesn't require to know Moodle, then it could be answerable.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thanks for your reply. I had edited my question. Seek for your adivce. Once again, thank you very much.